# How can i get separate tables for manager , owner , visitor as i am using rolify gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rolify

I am new to stackoverflow and i want to implement user with multiple roles .
I had started with rolify gem . I had generated 3 devise users manager , owner , user (visitor).

> Association used for my application is

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:visitor) if self.roles.blank?
  end       
end
```

---

```
class Owner < User
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     after_create :assign_default_role
      def assign_default_role
        self.add_role(:owner) if self.roles.blank?
      end               
end
```

---

```
class Manager < User
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:moderator) if self.roles.blank?
  end          
end
```

---

My concern is i am using rolify gem to assign role but i want to keep manager , owner , visitor table separate but if i didn't use Single table inheritance then how can i able to implement roles and keep table separate

---